# comma delimit javascript/asp line

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

What is the correct way to comma delimit this line, I keep getting javascript errors:

```
<a href="javascript:doSubmit(<%= pound & rs("AdvertiserID")%>, <%=rs("AdvertiserName")%>)">
```

Its Friday, what can I say...

The <%=rs("AdvertiserName")%>) can have single quotes in it, such as Dillard's and needs to be delimited, how would I add them? so I would end up with doSubmit(5432, "Dillard's")?

Thanks, R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to swap the positions of your final double quote and close parenthesis:

)"   instead of   ")

Comment: You are correct, thank you (it is Friday)...

The <%=rs("AdvertiserName")%>) is a string and can have single quote marks in it, such as Dillard's and it needs single or double quote marks around it so that it won't fail, any ideas?

Comment: You can escape the single quotes - call replace like this: <%= rs("AdvertiserName").Replace("'", @"\'") %>

Comment: flavour04 - if my answer resolved your problem, please give me an answer flag

Comment: Ray, it didn't resolve the issue, kept throwing an error message 'doesnt support function' otherwise i would have given the tick.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Ray, it wasn't exact but it did point me in the right direction so i am giving it too you ::)  Have a good one and a merry xmans...

Comment: thanx, and a merry one to you as well - did you need to use 'ToString()' or something to make it work?